# Why does strtof not print proper float?

Tags: c, floating-point-conversion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  char aaa[35] = "1.25";
  char* bbb = &(aaa[0]);
  char** ccc = &(bbb);
  float a = strtof(*ccc, ccc);
  printf("%f\n", a);
  return 0;
}
```

The code I wrote above should print `1.25`, but according to codepad (online C compiler), it does not print `1.25`. On codepad, it prints `2097152.000000` . Here's the [codepad link](http://codepad.org/yJvvONGZ)

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: What does it print then? I got [1.250000](http://ideone.com/Rs0Aru) on ideone

Comment: http://codepad.org/ doesn't print 1.25 when the code above is compiled and run

Comment: So what output are you getting?

Comment: your codepad link above doens't link to the compiler output

Comment: http://codepad.org/yJvvONGZ

Comment: why don't simply use `strtof(aaa, NULL)` or use a separate variable for `str_end` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof

Answer (score 5, accepted):

codepad has an old version of gcc, and presumably of the standard C library. Apparently, `strtof` is not being declared by the header files you include. (`strtof` was added in C99.)

Try using an online service with a postdiluvian version of gcc. Or explicitly add the correct declaration:

```
float strtof(const char* ptr, char** end_ptr);
```

What's happening is that without the declaration, the compiler defaults the return type of the function to `int`. Since the function actually returns a float, the float is being interpreted as (not converted to) an integer, and then that integer is converted to a float.

No warning is produced, presumably because -Wall is not in the compiler options, and/or the C standard being used allows the use of non-declared functions.

Comment: @ArunA.S: Yeah. Do you think I exaggerated too much? It's eight years old.